# Reveal.js - prevent scaling contents of an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, responsive-design, reveal.js

I'm using [RevealJs](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/).

One of the slides has an `iframe` sourcing an external website. When the page is scaled down, the iframe - including the contents - scales down. How can I change it so that just the `width` and `height` of the iframe changes, but not the content of the iframe?

Comment: May you provide your code?

Comment: I cannot unfortunately, but you can see how the code works by looking at the examples here: https://libraries.io/bower/reveal-js. You can also try it yourself via https://github.com/slara/generator-reveal.